# Appwrite : failed to register an account

Tags: reactjs, appwrite

[image]

What happened, I wanted to register an account but got an error like in the picture.What happened, I wanted to try registering a new account, but a 403 error occurred.

The response I got:

```
Invalid Origin. Register your new client (local host) as a new Web platform on your project console dashboard
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same question as the one shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77782380/8509670

(I have added the answer there)