# Appwrite : failed to create new user

Tags: reactjs, appwrite

I just tried using Appwrite for my website needs.

I am trying to create a form on my website which aims to register new users so they can log in to the application I created.

But when I send the input data to APPWRITE I get an error like in the picture, the error code is 403 and the server response is as follows: "Invalid Origin. Register your new client (127.0.0.1) as a new Web platform on your project console dashboard"

[image]

This is the response from the server :
[image]

I've tried looking for answers in all sources, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project on Appwrite, you must register your application by adding it as a web app in the Appwrite console. You can achieve this by clicking on **Web** in the **Add a platform** section.

[image: Appwrite Console]

This is necessary to authorize your application to communicate with Appwrite.

Comment: I have followed your instructions, first I have to input "name" and "hostname", what do I use for the "hostname"? does it use the example "localhost:300"?

I use "localhost:300" but it fails?

Comment: `localhost` is the hostname in this scenario. Hostnames don't contain ports. By the way, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are 2 different hostnames, so make sure you set the one that you're using (or you can add both if you use both).